# maven logging: info and error work but debug dont

Tags: java, maven, logging, plugins

I wrote a maven plugin and use also logging based on `org.apache.maven.plugin.logging.Log`. Info i sent and also errors do well, but no debug info although debug info from elsewhere can be seen. I use with `-e` option and with `-debug` option.

I use both maven and the maven plugin api with version 3.9.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `-debug` option. See `mvn --help`:

```
-X,--debug                             Produce execution debug output
```

Note the double hyphen.

Comment: thank you, I cannot reproduce my problem, all ok, thank you. 
-debug seems to work as --debug.. I use maven 3.9.2